# Angular distribution app not working as spected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, rootscope

I have developed an application with angular, but when I build the distribution application with grunt I have an strange behaviour of my application.
For example:

```
console.log("START");   
AuthService.refresh(LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId).then(function() {
    console.log("USER LOADED");
    $state.go('main.documents');
});
```

and in main.documents I have:

```
console.log("DOCUMENTS");
```

so the flow should be (the flow that I have in my production files):

```
log-->START
log-->USER LOADED
log-->DOCUMENTS
```

but the flow that I get in the production files is the following:

```
log-->START
log-->DOCUMENTS
log-->USER LOADED
```

and in my documents view my $rootScope where I save my user details it is empty and it fails all the time.

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl',
  authenticate: false
});

$stateProvider.state('main', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  authenticate: true
});

$stateProvider.state('main.documents', {
  url: 'documents',
  templateUrl: 'views/main/documents.html',
  controller: 'MainDocumentsCtrl',
  authenticate: true
});
$stateProvider.state('main.information', {
  url: 'information',
  templateUrl: 'views/main/managing-information.html',
  controller: 'MainInformationCtrl',
  authenticate: true
});
$stateProvider.state('main.calendar', {
  url: 'calendar',
  templateUrl: 'views/main/calendar.html',
  controller: 'MainCalendarCtrl',
  authenticate: true
});
$stateProvider.state('main.notices', {
  url: 'notices',
  templateUrl: 'views/main/notices.html',
  controller: 'MainNoticesCtrl',
  authenticate: true
});
$stateProvider.state('main.settings', {
  url: 'settings',
  templateUrl: 'views/main/settings.html',
  controller: 'MainSettingsCtrl',
  authenticate: true
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
}])
```

User authentication:

```
  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'LoopBackAuth', 'Authentication', function($rootScope, $state, LoopBackAuth, AuthService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
      // redirect to login page if not logged in
      if (toState.authenticate && !LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $rootScope.returnTo = {
          state: toState,
          params: toParams
        };
        $state.go('login');
      }
    });

    // Get data from localstorage after pagerefresh
    // and load user data into rootscope.
    if (LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId && !$rootScope.currentUser) {
      console.log("USER LOGGED IN");
      AuthService.refresh(LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId).then(function() {
        console.log("USER LOADED");

        $state.go('main.documents');
      });
    }

  }]);
```

Comment: Could you provide `$stateProvider` configuration?

Comment: @AntonStepanenkov added to the question

Comment: Code snippets lack the context, which is important. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At which moment do you check is user authenticated? Seems like your authentication check doesn't prevent user from visiting `main.documents` state.

Comment: @AntonStepanenkov added more code, taking some info maybe the resolve parameter into the state could solve the problem but I dont really know how to do it

Comment: I don't know is LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId, but seems like it cold be `true` even is user isn't authenticated.

Comment: The thing is that my user values added to the $rootScope are undefined inside my controller when I build the app. I have done a test using a setTime in my controller of 100 ms and after that ms the $rootScope have the data available but not if it is used just when the controller is loaded.